# Can not compile asterisk on OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: c++, c, macos, asterisk, osx-mavericks

I download the source code of asterisk on my macbook pro, which the OS X version is 10.9 ,then following the README.txt to compile it, but it failed ,and then I tried almost all the release version, but all the compiled results are the same, the compile error is as following,please help me to check it ,and how can I compile it on Mavericks; Appreciate!

> ranlib libmxml.a gcc -o menuselect menuselect.o strcompat.o
>   menuselect_stub.o mxml/libmxml.a 
>  Generating input for menuselect
>   ...
>  menuselect/menuselect --check-deps menuselect.makeopts 
>   menuselect/menuselect --check-deps menuselect.makeopts 
>  
>   Generating embedded module rules ...
>            [CC] stereorize.c ->
>   stereorize.o
>  error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
>  make[1]: ***
>   [stereorize.o] Error 1
>  make:**  [utils] Error 2

Comment: I don't think the compiler in OS X support higher optimization levels than 4 IIRC. You may want to take a look in the config file/makefile and see if you can somehow set the CFLAGS to use -O4 or -O3 instead.

Comment: If you encounter further incompatibilities with `clang` (the compiler that comes with Xcode), you may want to use `gcc47` or `gcc48` instead. Install that via `homebrew`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-O4" nor "-O3" work...

> sh-3.2# make ASTCFLAGS="-O4"    [LD] chan_iax2.o iax2-parser.o iax2-provision.o -> chan_iax2.so
>
> ld: lto: could not merge in
>   iax2-parser.o because 'Linking globals named 'ast_tvdiff_sec': symbol
>   multiply defined!', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 3.3svn, from
>   Apple Clang 5.0 (build 500.2.79)' for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make[1]: *** [chan_iax2.so] Error 1
>
> make: *** [channels] Error 2

Comment: Probably could have put that in the comments section.

Comment: Or added a text description of what this actually means.